# Getting XSRF check failed when curling file through php

Tags: php, curl, jira

I have the follow code trying to upload an attachment to a Jira issue:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/JT-1/attachments');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
$post = array(
    "file"=>"@/tmp/Screen_Shot_2012_10_18_at_2.58.33_PM.png",
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

however I am getting an error back saying:

```
XSRF check failed
```

What do I have to do to prevent getting this error?

Comment: You have to scrape the form for the XSRF token and maintain cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that i need to add the header:

```
X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck
```

to my request.